# C# get url parameter namevaluecollection from rewritten url

Tags: c#, url-rewriting, uri, url-parameters, url-parsing

If the url is not rewritten say like this

```
&tag=sql&page=3
```

I would get the parameter collection like this

```
var parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
```

But if I have something like this

```
/tag/sql-i/page/3/
```

That doesn't work.

What would be the best way to achieve the same result with a rewritten url?

Thanks

Comment: Parse it yourself with `string.Split`?

Comment: @L.B I think that is a valid answer. The Segments of the URI would get him what he needs.